# Django project not recognising Numpy Dependency

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy

my django project does not recognise my numpy and pandas dependencies.I have installed numpy and pandas through pycharm but for some reason they are not recognised. I run my project through the terminal by doing "python3 manage.py runserver"in the desired directory where I have saved the numpy and pandas libraries. Here is my code:

```
   from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
   from django import forms
   import pandas as pd

   def read_excel(ExcelFileName):
   File = pd.read_excel(ExcelFileName)
   return File

   template_name1 = 'multiplication/detail.html'

    class myForm(forms.Form):
    quantity1 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    quantity2 = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    def multiply_two_integers(x,y):
       return x*y

  def my_view(request):
     read_excel
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = myForm(request.POST)
        if (form.is_valid()):
           x = form.cleaned_data['quantity1']
           y = form.cleaned_data['quantity2']
           product = multiply_two_integers(x, y)
           multiplied = True
           return render(request, template_name1, {'form': 
           form,'product': product, 'multiplied': multiplied })
       else:
           multiplied = False
           form = myForm()
           return render(request,template_name1,{'form': form, 
           'multiplied': multiplied} )
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
   in <module>
    from multiplication import views
    File 
    "/Users/NikolasPapastavrou/firstProject/multiplication/views.py", 
    line 11, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
     File "/Users/NikolasPapastavrou/firstProject/pandas/__init__.py", 
     line 19, in <module>
     "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
      ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Please help me understand what is wrong with my project. Find attached an image of all the libraries I am using.[image]

Comment: how do you run manage.py?

Comment: Is PyCharm set to the correct virtual environment where NumPy and Pandas are installed?

Comment: I do not know how to check for the virtual environment

Comment: It is the one in the screenshot

Comment: PyCharm is probably pointing at a different Python install than what you are running in the terminal. In the terminal, run `which python3` - what path does it give you?